# Why are some of the unit tests dim, in Test Explorer?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, visual-studio-2019

I'm running the unit tests in a project we have. All of the tests pass, but some of them are dim, whereas others are normal in brightness. I'm using VS 2019 Enterprise. I'm guessing that this indicates something new, in terms of what it's conveying to the user. I just don't know what that might be. Here's a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Never mind. I believe what that's telling me is those test (e.g.: CodeWriter has 3) haven't run. If I'm wrong about that, then please correct me.

Comment: You are correct. The tests are bright green when they have passed in the _latest_ test run; previous test runs are dimmed.